# Error with React Native Expo Notifications

Tags: react-native, push-notification, notifications, expo, expo-notifications

I am using Exp notifications, and works fine for all of my users. However a few of my users get this error `"Error Domain=UNErrorDomain Code=1 "Notifications are not allowed for this application" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Notifications are not allowed for this application}"`. Do you  have any idea what's going on and why only a few of them get this error? Thank you.

Comment: I have the same issue (only reported for a few users). Using RN bare workflow.

Comment: @ilyavf Check this https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/10893